# Marklogic entity property versus relationship for an effective Mastering

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I have a question around best practices in the design of entities in MarkLogic.
When we design a property under an entity, it can have classic types or also other entity types.

Example:

Entity A
|-id (string)
|-property1 (string)
|-property2 (string)
|-property3 (Entity B)

Entity B
|-id (string)
|-property1 (string)
|-property2 (string)

In designing relationships between entities, using different tools provided by Marklogic, to link entities we have different manners and I'd like to have your recommendation on when to use external entity as a property and when to use only a relationship

This is extremely important as I personally found that using entities as properties helps a lot in the mastering step and harmonization more than relationship

Any thoughts?